# Using esp_now for sending more than packet

Tags: c++, c, arduino-ide, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

The esp_now can not send more than 250 bytes. I have array with size 550 how can I sent this by using esp_now ?
The size of first packet should be 250, the second 250 and the size of third packet is 50.

```
 int8_t bs[550]={/*some int data*/};
esp_now_send(remoteMac, bs, sizeof(sensorData));
```

The parameters are:

1. A pointer to a 6-byte array containing the MAC number of the receiving device
2. A pointer to the buffer containing the message data
3. The size of the packet to be transmitted (250 bytes maximum)

Comment: What is the type of `bs`? The obvious way to do this is with a little pointer arithmetic, but the correct code cannot be stated without knowing the type of `bs`.

Comment: Apparently ESP-NOW only supports data up to 255 bytes. I saw this on https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_now.html . Therefore you must use multiple packets, therefore you must make up a way for the receiving one to know which packet it is.

Comment: @john, bs is 1D array

Comment: @oleva There seems to be some confusion here. If you have an array of 550 `int` then the size of that array is 2200 bytes (if each `int` is 4 bytes) or even 4400 bytes (if each `int` is 8 bytes). Also user253751's comment makes me think that this is more complicated than I realised.

Comment: Ok, I will use int8_t , my problem how to send from 1 to 250 and then from 251 to 501 and then from 502 to then end